# Tap / touch on link bubbling down even with higher z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a link which is positioned relative with very high z-index, however tapping on the link in android and ios browsers make the element which is below the link get tapped , clicked.

Here's the style,

```
li a {
background: linear-gradient(to right, #A5A5A5 0%, #EDEDED 50%, #A5A5A5 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
color: #254FAA !important;
display: block;
height: 40px;
position: relative;
z-index: 9999;
```

}

what could be wrong here, note that click using a mouse in desktop works just fine

Comment: hi, yes here, http://jsfiddle.net/9D3vy/1/